# How to check worker connection within spark-shell after using flintrock for setup

Tags: apache-spark

I am using flintrock to setup spark ec2 cluster.

After launching a cluster with flintrock, is the connection to the slave instances to master node correctly configured? Is there any way to check the connection within the spark-shell ?

Thanks much in advance.